# I want to change CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using visual studio 2019. When I use doubles, it uses "," instead ".". I get error if I use ".". I searched around and I can change it but I want to change it inside setting so that it automatically uses "." and not ",".

this is code i use.

```
double d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

and if i type 4.6 (decimal with .) it gets this error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.Double.Parse(String s)
   at project3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\a2bme\source\repos\project3\Program.cs:line 9
```

but 4,6 works fine. I have worked with some other languages and am used to ".".

edit:

I know about `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and want a way without using it every time.

Comment: Does the code throw errors or are you asking about visual studio here?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried and what is erroring - include as much detail as you can.

Comment: Chance is you want to change the CurrentCulture or specify a different one during parsing

Comment: Just specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when parsing and formatting.

Comment: you can just one NumberDecimalSeparator at a time. and it can be set via creating a CultureInfo and assign it to the current thread. if you want to have multiple separators, you must write some parsing extension methods that can process the input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "," is valid and "." is not valid
A simple solution can be this.
Now you can enter 4.5 or 4,5 and both will work.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine().Replace(".", ",");
        double d = double.Parse(input);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```